# No way to unfavourite a question in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, user-interface, bookmarks

When I press the "favourite" button beneath a question in the Android app, there is no way to unfavourite it (from the app). I receive a success message, but when I click the button again, it just says I have already favourited the question.
If this was never intended to be a feature, I will make a feature request.